# No read/write premisions on new folders (samba)

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a share using samba called share. If I do `Chmod +R 777 folder/*`
the files already in the folder get the rights but if I copy folders from my other PC using the samba share I get a no rights error. I can get it to work if I do `Chmod +R 777 folder/*` again but I have to do that for every folder. Is there a way Ubuntu does this automatically every time a new folder is added?

Comment: oh sorry that is just my auto correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit */etc/samba/smb.conf*.  Open it as root, go to the end, where the shared folder you want to configure is placed and add the parameter

`inherit permissions = yes`

at the end of the specific folder section.  Then save the file and either reboot your system or restart samba services manually by typing

`sudo service smbd restart`
`sudo service nmbd restart`

in a terminal window.

This tells samba to give all parent folder permissions to each newly created item automatically.  If, for example, the parent folder uses 777, all newly created files will be given the same permissions.